# How can you show text in-game?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I downloaded a Minecraft map but when I open the the doors there is a text that comes on the screen that says "open and close". How do they do this? Do they use commands?

Comment: You can attach images to your question within the edit tab. Once you click edit on your question, click the image icon (The rectangle with mountains and a sun inside of it next to the curly brackets { } ). You can choose to browse images, drag the image into the box, or paste the image in.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide screenshots? It's hard to know what kind of message you're referring to since it could be a message in chat, actionbar, title, floating text, etc.

You can try to run any of these commands to see if it's the message you're seeing:

```
/title @s actionbar open and close
/title @s title open and close
/tellraw @s {"rawtext":[{"text":"open and close"}]}
/say open and close
/w @s open and close
```

Comment: Ok am going send the screenshot

Comment: I don't know how to send the pictures but if u hav what's app please send me ur number

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on your screen, or on the side? If you mean the screen, then do: */title @a title* 
If you mean on the side, then do: */say*